# My form in Python Django is not submitting

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm making a form involving making a schedule using Django, but for some reason the form is not submitting. I checked using SQLite DB Browser and nothing seems to be submitting.

```
# choices.py

COURSE_NAME_CHOICES = (('a-plus', 'A+ PC Technician'), ('advance java', 'Advance Java/J2EE/Weblogic/Websphere'), ('a-s master', 'Agile-Scrum Master'), ('android mobile', 'Android Mobile Development'), ('autocad', 'AutoCAD'), ('bio-info', 'Bio-info Database Training course'), ('ba', 'Business Analyst (BA'), ('c-sharp', 'C# .Net'), ('ccna', 'CCNA Voice'), ('ceh', 'Certified Ethical Hacking'), ('checkpoint', 'Checkpoint Security Firewall Course'), ('ccie', 'Cisco CCIE IP Telephony'))
LOCATION_CHOICES = (('south_plainfield', 'South Plainfield'), ('hackensack', 'Hackensack'), ('fairfield', 'Fairfield'), ('eatontown', 'Eatentown'))
ROOM_CHOICES = (('A', 'South Plainfield A: CNA/MCSE'), ('B', 'South Plainfield B: SAS/.Net'), ('C', 'South Plainfield C: Cisco'), ('D', 'South Plainfield D: QA/.Net/Java'), ('E', 'South Plainfield E: Weblogic/Java/MCSE'), ('F', 'South Plainfield F: Unix/Linux'), ('G', 'South Plainfield G: Oracle/Clinic/Datawarehouse'))
START_TIME_CHOICES = (('eight-thirty am', '8:30 AM'), ('nine am', '9:00 AM'))
END_TIME_CHOICES = (('eight-thirty am', '8:30 AM'), ('nine am', '9:00 AM'))
INSTRUCTOR_CHOICES = (('adewale', 'Adewale Akinokun'), ('ajay', 'Ajay Kumar'))
TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES = (('six', 6), ('ten', 10))
HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES = (('two_and_half', 2.5), ('three', 3))
FREQUENCY_CHOICES = (('sunday', 'Sunday'), ('monday', 'Monday'), ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'), ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'), ('thursday', 'Thursday'), ('friday', 'Friday'), ('saturday', 'Saturday'))
STATUS_CHOICES = (('active', 'Active'), ('inactive', 'Inactive'), ('expired', 'Expired'), ('pending', 'Pending'))
INTERVAL_CHOICES = (('one_day', '1 Day'), ('two_days', '2 Days'))

# models.py

from django.db import models
from schedule.choices import *
import datetime

class Schedule(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=COURSE_NAME_CHOICES, default='a-plus')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=ROOM_CHOICES, default='A')
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INSTRUCTOR_CHOICES, default='adewale')
    total_hours = models.IntegerField(choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, default='six')
    hours_per_class = models.FloatField(choices=HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES, default='four_and_half')
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=FREQUENCY_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default='one_day')

def __str__(self):
    return self.course_name

# forms.py

from django import forms
from schedule.models import Schedule
from schedule.choices import *
import datetime

class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    course_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COURSE_NAME_CHOICES, initial='a-plus', label="Course Name")
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, initial='south_plainfield', label="Location")
    room = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROOM_CHOICES, initial='A', label="Room")
    start_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'), input_formats=('%m/%d/%Y'), label="Start Date")
    start_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, initial='eight-thirty am', label="Start Time")
    end_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, initial='eight-thirty am', label="End Time")
    instructor = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INSTRUCTOR_CHOICES, initial='adewale', label="Instructor")
    total_hours = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, initial='six', label="Total Hours")
    hours_per_class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=HOURS_PER_CLASS_CHOICES, initial='four_and_half', label="Hours Per Class")
    frequency = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FREQUENCY_CHOICES, label="Frequency")
    status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, label="Status")
    interval = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, initial='one_day', label="Interval")

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ('course_name', 'location', 'room', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'instructor', 'total_hours', 'hours_per_class', 'frequency', 'status', 'interval',)

        widgets = {}

# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from schedule import views as  schedule_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^start_one_schedule/$', schedule_views.start_One_Schedule, name='start_one_schedule'),
]

# views.py

def start_One_Schedule(request):
    form = ScheduleForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScheduleForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request, 'schedule/schedule.html', {})
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'schedule/start_one_schedule.html', {'form': form})

# start_one_schedule.html

{% block main_content %}
<h2>Initial Course Schedule</h2>
<br>
<form id="schedule_form" method="post" action="/schedule/start_one_schedule/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <table class="init_sched_form">
            <tr class="init_sched_row">
                <td class="init_sched_label">{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
                <td class="init_sched_field">{{ field }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Initial Schedule</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The form does manage to display on the html itself. It's just that the submit button won't work at all. I made sure to double check everything and I'm 90% sure that I did everything correctly. Does anyone have an idea? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

EDIT: I think I figured out the problem. By showing the form errors in the template, I was able to see that some of the entries several fields were invalid. I fixed two of them by turning the choices in choices.py with integers and floats into strings, which is not a graceful fix but it works for this case.

Second, the start date field was invalid because apparently it only accepts dates in the format of YYYY-MM-DD and not MM/DD/YYYY like I want it, so I changed the initial back, but if anyone has solution to that please tell me.

Finally, the final two errors are the ones that are stumping me. Here they are:

status - Enter a list of values.

frequency - Select a valid choice. ['tuesday', 'wednesday'] is not one of the available choices.

Both of these are multiple choice fields, frequency being multiple selection checkbox and status being radio select. I have no idea what these errors mean, since there are only set choices to choose from, so I don't know how to "enter a list of values" or why those aren't valid choices.

Comment: What does it mean "the submit button won't work at all"? Does the URL not change?

Comment: Yes. The URL stays the same. There might be a split second where the page flashes but it stays on the same page.

Comment: Your print(form.errors) does not return anything. So the errors are printed on the console, then it renders the same thing again. But you're not showing the errors in the template. Add {{form.errors}} above the field loop.

Comment: I edited the question due to new discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In general

You're overriding and duplicating things that work out of the box. Model forms generate fields surprisingly well. Setting aside the bit about charfields, you can reduce your form to the following:

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ('course_name', 'location', 'room', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'instructor', 'total_hours', 'hours_per_class', 'frequency', 'status', 'interval',)
        widgets = { 'frequency': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 'status': forms.RadioSelect }
```

### CharField is not a container

You cannot use a `CharField` for multiple choices. It only holds one item, of type string. So any value passed to it is coerced to string representation `['foo', 'bar']` for a list. This doesn't match the choices so validation fails. This typically is solved with a ManyToManyRelation to a Frequency model. Yes, the data is "static", but does it really make that much difference to use a database table here.

A solution gaining popularity is to use `ArrayField` or `JSONField` from `django.contrib.postgres`. While it works, it make relations a lot harder, so best used if this information is only displayed and not filtered on.

### RadioSelect returns one item

This is basically the reverse. Now you're trying to use a widget that returns one value for a form field that expects multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I fixed it. However, if I replaced the Schedule Form with what you wrote, wouldn't I need to confirm that some of those fields are ChoiceFields? Also, I solved the final two problems even though they were still CharFields.

Comment: Model forms are generated from model definitions. If a field on a model defines choices, Django will pick a ChoiceField for the model form (Select as widget by default). When it is a foreign key, it will also pick a ChoiceField, but will generate the choices using the related manager.